# How to create pair of values based on similarity on time window and a factor value in R or python

Tags: python, r

I have the following CSV file of the following format format

```
Id =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
ASN =c(15169,15169,1299,15169,15169,1299,15169,1299,1299)
Value =c(253,48,17,33,38,46,253,46,40)
TimeWindow =c('2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 18:00:00','2017-10-05 19:00:00','2017-10-05 12:00:00','2017-10-05 12:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00')
sampleData = data.frame(Id, ASN, Value,TimeWindow)
```

I want to a pair of different ASN for each similar time windows per user id. Let me try to explain  what I mean with example

> The first two rows of id#1 are in the same time window but shouldn't
>   be considered as a pair since they have similar ASN value(15169)

And

> The 3rd and the 4th rows of id#1 are not pairs since they are not in the same time window.

And

> The 5th and the 6th rows of id#1 are pairs since they are in the same time window with different ASN value.

And

> 7th row of Id#2 and the average Value 8th & 9th rows (averaged, since they have same ASN) are pairs (since they have different ASN (15169 & 1299) in the same time window (2017-10-05 17:00:00)

The final result will look like the following

```
Id = c(1,1,2,2)
ASN = c(15169,1299,15169,1299)
Value =c(38,46 , 253,43)
TimeWindow = c('2016-10-05 12:00:00','2016-10-05 12:00:00','2016-10-05 17:00:00','2016-10-05 17:00:00')
FinalResult = data.frame(Id,ASN, Value,TimeWindow)
```

I really appreciate if you have any idea on how to approach this with R or Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Id =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
ASN =c(15169,15169,1299,15169,15169,1299,15169,1299,1299)
Value =c(253,48,17,33,38,46,253,46,40)
TimeWindow =c('2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 18:00:00','2017-10-05 19:00:00','2017-10-05 12:00:00','2017-10-05 12:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00','2017-10-05 17:00:00')
sampleData = data.frame(Id, ASN, Value,TimeWindow)

library(dplyr)

sampleData %>%
  group_by(Id, TimeWindow, ASN) %>%     # for each combination
  summarise(Value = mean(Value)) %>%    # get the mean value
  filter(n_distinct(ASN) > 1) %>%       # keep the ones that have pairs
  ungroup() %>%                         # forget the grouping
  select(Id, ASN, Value, TimeWindow)    # keep relevant columns

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      Id   ASN Value          TimeWindow
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>              <fctr>
# 1     1  1299    46 2017-10-05 12:00:00
# 2     1 15169    38 2017-10-05 12:00:00
# 3     2  1299    43 2017-10-05 17:00:00
# 4     2 15169   253 2017-10-05 17:00:00
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, I didn't know that dplyr is this powerful. I should dig more into it.

Comment: You can definitely use data.table package and syntax as well to achieve this. Maybe someone can post a data.table solution. I just tend to use dplyr more. :-)